# How to fetch address fields in email template in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

How to fetch address fields like phone number,country name in  Magento 2's email template?

Answer (score 0):

There are two address type, one is shipping address, other is billing address.

If you want to get city in billing address you can try this:

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().getCity()}}
```

Other information is the same, but if you want to get street line you need to use this:

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().getStreetLine(1)}}
```

1: Street line 1

2: Street line 2

Depend on your magento version, you can try 0 and 1. I don't remember which version use this.

Nice day!

Comment: Its not working..

Comment: Have any solution?